# Query the configured TwinCAT Static Routes using TwinCAT - ADS API

Tags: c#, twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

I am using the `Beckhoff.TwinCAT.Ads` Version = 6.0235 NuGet package in c#, I want to query the configured Static Routes:

[image: TwinCAT Static Routes]

I have tried with `TwinCAT.Ads.TcpRouter` and `TwinCAT.Router` namespaces with no success:

1. Is that possible?
2. Which class or method from the API should I use?

Expected Result:

`ICollection<RouteInfo>` or something similar

Thanks in advance for your help, any comment would be very appreciated.

Miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse the C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Target\StaticRoutes.xml file. This is the location where the static routes entries you see in the editor are stored.

Comment: i took me a while after i discovered it, nevertheless it only provides the actual static routes as you mentioned, i opened also a discussion on github and they provide me the official way to do this. The official way is described here: https://github.com/Beckhoff/ADS/issues/200 anyway thank you for your help

Comment: Okay, I got your question wrong. Thoght you tried this already :-)

Comment: you got it totally rigth, but nonetheless it was half the job needed, i just posted because maybe it can be interesting for other people looking for the same answer